# Firefox sometimes unable to detect HiDPI settings in Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome, firefox, display-resolution, hdpi

I use both regular Firefox (The one on the left in the screenshot) and the Firefox Developer Edition (The one on the right in the screenshot)

I have 4K monitors, and mostly Firefox detects this just fine. But sometimes it does not.

I can't really explain it any better: sometimes I start my computer, open regular Firefox and the interface is tiny.

I only ever have this issue in the regular Firefox, not in the Developer Edition. Most of the time I need a reboot to fix it.

(The dpi & devPixelsPerPx are the same value in both browsers, and changing those just does some weird scaling)

Does anyone know what's wrong?

[image: Firefox wrong dpi on the left]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a problem with Gnome Shell itself. It sets the DPI settings *too late*, or something, so Firefox (which starts on boot) is shown using a wrong scale.

Closing and re-opening didn't work, because Firefox kept running in the background. I had to `killall firefox` first.

Now I'm running into another problem: sometimes Gnome Shell doesn't detect the correct DPI settings AT ALL and every window (except the Gnome Shell titlebar) is shown very small...